Why is the complete life span mentioned between Adam and Noach, but not between Noach and Avraham?
When listing the generations between Adam and Noach, the Torah first says when each person had his 'important' son, then how long he lived after that, and then how long he lived altogether.
For example (Bereishis 5:3-5):

ויחי אדם שלשים ומאת שנה ויולד בדמותו כצלמו ויקרא את שמו שת: ויהיו ימי אדם אחרי הולידו את שת שמונה מאות שנה ויולד בנים ובנות: ויהיו כל ימי אדם אשר חי תשע מאות שנה ושלושים שנה וימת:
When Adam had lived 130 years, he begot a son in his likeness after his image, and he named him Seth: After the birth of Seth, Adam lived 800 years and begot sons and daughters: All the days that Adam lived came to 930 years; then he died:

This holds true up to and including Noach. However, after Noach, the complete count of years is no longer mentioned when lifting the generations until Avraham. For example (Bereishis 11:10-11):

אלה תולדות שם שם בן מאת שנה ויולד את ארפכשד שנתים אחר המבול: ויחי שם אחרי הולידו את ארפכשד חמש מאות שנה ויולד בנים ובנות:
This is the line of Shem. Shem was 100 years old when he begot Arpachshad, 2 years after the flood: After the birth of Arpachshad, Shem lived 500 years and begot sons and daughters:

Why the discrepancy? In other words, why was doing the math for us important between Adam and Noach, but not between Noach and Avraham?

I read in a sefer yesterday, don't know where but trying to locate it, that the lineage of Avraham is different than that of Noach, because mankind started anew and Avraham Avinu was the first that recognised G-d out of himself (Midrash) and with Avraham, G-ds light was revealed to the world. Why track back Avraham Avinu to people that did not recognise Hashem? That was what the sefer was telling us.

It looks like it is following the warning given to Adam haRishon, that Hashem stated in Bereshis 2:17:

וּמֵעֵ֗ץ הַדַּ֙עַת֙ ט֣וֹב וָרָ֔ע לֹ֥א תֹאכַ֖ל מִמֶּ֑נּוּ כִּ֗י בְּי֛וֹם אֲכׇלְךָ֥ מִמֶּ֖נּוּ מ֥וֹת תָּמֽוּת׃
but as for the tree of knowledge of good and bad, you must not eat of it; for on the day that you eat of it, you shall die.”

Midrash Pesikta Rabbathi 40:1 teaches

[וכן] לאדם כשבא לבראותו ונסתכל שהוא חוטא בעץ ואמר אם אני בורא אותו במידת הדין אין לו תקומה ואם לבראותו ברחמים רע הוא (מתענג) [התענוג] מה עשה שיתף שני המדות מדת הדין ומדת רחמים וברא אותו שנאמר ויצר ה' אלקים את האדם (שם שם ז') וכך עשה לו בזמן שחטא דנו בשתי המדות במדת הדין ובמדת רחמים במדת הדין שאמר לו ביום אכלך ממנו מות תמות (שם שם י"ז) וכיון שאכל גזר עליו מיתה ובמידת רחמים כיצד שיתף עם מדת הדין שלא פירש לו אם יום משלו ואם יום של הקדוש ברוך הוא שהוא אלף שנים כי אלף שנים בעיניך כיום אתמול וגו' (תהלים צ' ד') והוא חיה תשע מאות ושלשים והניח לבניו שבעים שנה שנא' ימי שנותינו בהם שבעים שנה וגו' (שם שם י') ולא עוד אלא כיון שאכל היו המלאכים משמיעים קולם לפני הקב"ה שנאמר וישמעו קול ה' אלקים (בראשית ג' ח') ומה היו אומרים רבונו של עולם מת והלך לו אותו שבגן שנאמר מתהלך בגן (שם) לא כך גזרת עליו כי ביום אכלך ממנו מות תמות אמר להם הקדוש ברוך הוא שמא פירשתי לו אם יום משלי אם יום משלו יום משלי אני נותן לו לרוח היום (שם) אני נותן לו תשע מאות ושלשים ומניח לבניו שבעים שנה לפיכך אמר דוד רבון העולמים אילולי שדנת את אדם הראשון ברחמים בשעה שאכל מן האילן לא חיה אפילו שעה אחת וכשם שדנת אותו ברחמים כך התקנת עמו שאתה היום דן את בניו ברחמים לעולם ה' דברך נצב מהו נצב קיים דברך שהתקנת עם האדם הראשון שכשם שדנת אותו ברחמים כך אתה דן את כל הדורות אחריו לעולם לכך נאמר לעולם ה' (מהו) לדור ודור אמונתך (מהו) למשפטיך עמדו היום
[Also when Hashem] came to creation of man and foresaw that he will sin with (eating from) the tree and said, "If I create him according to the measure of judgment - he will have no redeeming qualities, and if I create him according to the measure of mercy it will be bad, he (will enjoy) [the pleasure]. What did He do - He mixed/partnered the two measures, the measure of judgment and the measure of mercy, and created him (man/Adam) as it is said, "And the Lord G-d created man" Bereshis 2:7) And so He did to him at the time he (Adam) sinned according to both the measure of judgement and the measure of mercy. The measure of judgement told him that "on the day you eat from it you will die (Bereshis 2:17)" and since Adam ate he was sentenced to death.
And the measure of mercy? And if the day of the Holy One, blessed be He, is a thousand years, for in Your sight a thousand years are like yesterday (Tehilim 90:4) and he lived nine hundred and thirty years, and he left to his sons seventy years, the days of our years are seventy years and ... (Tehilim 90:10) And not only that but, as he was eating the angels  were uttering their voice before the Almighty, as it was said, *and they heard the voice of the Hashem G-d. *(Bereshis 3:8) and what were they saying? The Master of the World died and went to the one in the garden, as it is said, moving about in the garden etc. (Bereshis 3:8) Is this not what You decreed for him, that on the day you eat from it you will die?
The Holy One, blessed be He, said to them, "Would I have interpreted to him whether my day is mine, whether his day is mine, I give him to the spirit of this day (there) I give him nine hundred and thirty years and leave his sons seventy years.
Thus said David, the Lord of the worlds, had it not been for the fact that you judged the first Adam with mercy when he ate from the tree, he did not live for even one hour, and just as you judged him with mercy, so you decreed with him that today you judge his sons with mercy for the world, O God, your word is justified. This is how you judge all the generations after him for ever and ever. For this it is said to the world of God (what is it) for generation and generation your faith (what is it) for your judgments stand today.

We can conclude from the midrash, that for all generations prior to the flood the full count of their years signifies that their life span followed that of Adam haRishon who died on the day he was created in G-d's days. Eash one (except for Methushelach) died on the same G-d's day (close to 1000 years) as each one was born, and Methushelach saw the beginning of the next due to his righteousness. Finally, the judgement of 120 years (Bereshis 6:3) was defered for the time after the flood and then of 70 years by the times of Moshe and David.
Rabbeinu Bachya makes a related note. We do not find mentioning of death in descendats of Shem, like we find among the earlier generations from Adam till Noach. This is because the kingship of David came from Shem, and there is no death for Mashiyach ben David.
